# IronController Helpers not working

Tags: meteor, iron-router

i am farely new to meteor, so it might be obvious.

I am trying to define some routes:

```
Router.route('/translations', {name:'translation.index'}); 
Router.route('/translations/:_id', {name:'translation.show'});
```

I also have defined a Controller which should define how to get the Data:

```
TranslationIndexController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'TranslationIndex',
   data: function () {
        return Translations.find();
    },
   sayHello: function(){
       return 'hello';
   }      
});
```

I have some Collection that is just fetched and some random tempalte helper. My template looks like this:

```
<template name="TranslationIndex">
            TestOutput:
            {{sayHello}}
            {{#each data}}
            <li><a href="#">askljdfh</a></li>
            {{/each}}
</template>
```

But neither my hello nor my collection is shown. PS: I have checked if my collection contains data by using Translations.find().count() in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the controller in your route, e.g.,

```
Router.route('/translations', {
  name:'translation.index',
  controller: TranslationIndexController
});
```

The data should then be available.

Comment: it tells me that the TranslationIndexController is not defined. Maybe this is related to the load order. I have my stuff in 2 files: My Controller is defined in client/views/translations/translation.js and my routes are under lib/router.js

Comment: The easiest thing to do is add your controller definitions to your /lib folder and take them out of your client views folders.  Your controller variable is not being defined on the server, but it is being called on the server because router.js runs in both environments.  So it is not load order per se but where you are placing the files that is causing the problem.